# After migrating from a Wubi install (12.10 x64) I can't mount a USB flash drive

Tags: wubi, mount

After using the Wubi migration script and booting into my Ubuntu install, when I plug in my USB flash drive I receive a prompt that says "Unable to open a folder for PENDRIVE. No application is registered as handling this file." If I attempt to open the drive from the launcher, nothing happens.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with the ACLs (access control lists). I'm not sure when the problem started (I think with release 12.10), but ironically it happened to me last week so I knew what to look for.

Anyway here is the low down... if you check the access control list on the Wubi install it looks like this:

```
# file: media/bcbc
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:bcbc:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Whereas on the migrated install it looks like this:

```
bcbc@23:34:50:~$ getfacl /media/bcbc
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/bcbc
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
```

As you can see it's missing this: `user:bcbc:r-x`

**Solution**

The simplest solution is to remove the directory as it gets recreated automatically (substituting your username in place of `bcbc`):

```
sudo rmdir /media/bcbc
```

Or you can simply reinstate the ACL by running the following command (again substituting your username, twice):

```
sudo setfacl -m u:bcbc:rx /media/bcbc
```

This is what it looks like:

```
bcbc@23:34:53:~$ sudo setfacl -m u:bcbc:rx /media/bcbc
[sudo] password for bcbc: 
bcbc@23:35:42:~$ getfacl /media/bcbc
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/bcbc
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:bcbc:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::---

bcbc@23:35:44:~$
```

I've marked it as an issue on the migration script ([wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) and [github](https://github.com/bcbc/Wubi-move/issues/22)) and will fix it in the next release, probably need to add the `-A` option to the `rsync` commands to copy across the access control list.